# SparkSQL timeseries data: how to apply custom aggregation function on window in DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an incoming Data frame, in the following format (timestamp, data1, data2):

```
2015-09-25T11:00:00.000Z "test" "value1"
2015-09-25T12:00:00.000Z "test" "value2"
2015-09-25T13:00:00.000Z "test" "value3"
```

I need to "look back" based on window size and perform aggregation on third column, so if a window size is 1 hour, then the output should be:

```
2015-09-25T11:00:00.000Z "test" "value1"
2015-09-25T12:00:00.000Z "test" "value1, value2"
2015-09-25T13:00:00.000Z "test" "value2, value3"
```

for 2 hour window:

```
2015-09-25T11:00:00.000Z "test" "value1"
2015-09-25T12:00:00.000Z "test" "value1, value2"
2015-09-25T13:00:00.000Z "test" "value1, value2, value3"
```

I was thinking about writing custom aggregation function which can group and using it with Spark SQL Windowed operation, but it is not supported in Spark 1.6. So maybe somebody was working on the tasks like that before and can help?